# Can Pusher messages be received on Android/iOS app when the app is closed or phone is turned off

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pusher

Can [Pusher](https://pusher.com) messages be received on Android/iOS app when the app is closed or the phone is turned off?

What i expect to happen...

1. When phone is on & app is on, it's pretty straight forward from the Pusher docs on how to react to pusher messages sent to the app.
2. When phone is on & app is closed, the phone should receive a notification that something has been sent to the app.
3. When phone is turned off, a notification should be received by the phone when it's turned back on to notify that something has been sent to the app.

Are these even possible? If yes, what are some suggestions to lookout for? If no, what can be some workaround?

Comment: Can you please clarify what pusherIO is? Can you reference the library docs?

Comment: www.pusher.com - real time message passing platform as a service for connected clients... Somewhat like pubnub

Comment: To clarify: what library are you using? What is pusherIO?

Comment: PusherIO was the former more popular name. Now it's called only pusher i guess. I am taking about the pusher SDK for Android. I have not started using it yet. I am only trying to understand the scope of how it maybe implemented in practice for phones. If anyone in the community has experience with pusher SDK for Android, i am expecting he/she would be able to help me assess the scopes of the SDK as i mentioned in the question. Depending on the clarification of that scope, i may start trying it out. So far, i do not think my specific queries have been addressed clearly in the docs.

Comment: Pusher was previously referred to as PusherApp (but still named "Pusher") since it had that domain and Twitter handle. Since funding in 2011 they have the Pusher domain and Twitter handle too.

Comment: Ok... But my question here is still seeking some answers for the cases mentioned. I am not sure how/if pusher enables the mentioned use cases

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When an application using Pusher moves into the background on iOS and Android the connection to Pusher will likely stay active for a few minutes. But eventually that connection will be closed. You can't stop that happening within your application (although there may be a "hack" around stating your app is a Voice app when submitting to the Apps store).

Therefore, you should monitor your application moving to the background and put a fallback in place to delivery messages to the phone when it's not connected.

Please see [How get pusher events when the iOS app go to the background?](https://github.com/lukeredpath/libPusher/issues/141) for libPusher (the Pusher iOS library).

Here's an extract from the [Android Processes & Threads Lifecycle docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle) on a "Service Process":

> A process that is running a service that has been started with the startService() method and does not fall into either of the two higher categories. Although service processes are not directly tied to anything the user sees, they are generally doing things that the user cares about (such as playing music in the background or downloading data on the network), so the system keeps them running unless there's not enough memory to retain them along with all foreground and visible processes.

So, running a Pusher instance in such a thread is a viable option.

However, there will still be occasions where the user goes offline. In that situation your server you can detect if a user is online by [querying the Pusher HTTP API](https://pusher.com/docs/server_api_guide/interact_rest_api#querying-application-state) or by using [WebHooks](https://pusher.com/docs/webhooks) where your server can be instantly informed if the user has gone offline or come back online.

Using the mechanisms above you can facilitate [smart notifications](https://blog.pusher.com/smart-notifications-with-pusher-and-sendgrid/); if the user is online (the app is in the foreground) then send the message to them by Pusher, if they are offline (the app is in the background) then use an alternative mechanism for delivery (native Push Notification, SMS or email).

Comment: Great answer @leggetter. Thanks for the answer. You mentioned a library specifically for iOS. What kind of work around or suggestion would you have for Android? Would you suggest using a background service that keeps a pusher connection alive even when app is closed? (very inefficient of course). Would be great if you can edit your answer with this information. Thanks.

Comment: @syedrakib I've done some further investigation about Android and added the relevant information to the answer.